# NPE when creating visible Activities Robolectric 2.3

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

For example I have two activities MainActivity and NextStartedActivity.

onCreate() method in MainActivity

```
...
Intent intent = (new Intent(this, NextStartedActivity.class).putExtra("start", 1));
startActivity(intent);
```

For MainActivity this invocation works fine

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().visible().get();
```

onCreate() in NextStartedActivity

```
...
request_status = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("start");
textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
...
```

When I use invocation like above for NextStartedActivity, I have
`java.lang.NullPointerException at NextStartedActivityTest.java:89` but when I use

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(NextStartedActivity.class).get();
```

all works fine.

Please, give me understanding in differences of this ways with different activities. And is this equal to setupActivity()?

Comment: To help out, you need to share stacktrace and more code. It seems like something happens in your onCreate that causes the NPE.

Comment: I've refreshed my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the NPE is occurring on this line:

```
request_status = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("start");
```

then the problem is that you are not creating an intent in your test, which your code expects. Try something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext(),   
                NextStartedActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("start", 1);
Robolectric.buildActivity(NextStartedActivity.class).withIntent(intent).create().get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's works. Ok, but why 

nextStartedActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(NextStartedActivity.class).get();        
assertThat(nextStartedActivity).isNotNull; works too, I mean not fails?

Comment: Because if you do not explicitly call the create() on the activity controller in the test, onCreate on the activity does not get called, so that piece of code never executes. With robolectric you drive the lifecycle manually.